# Dynamic comparison with pandas AND

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary with each column as a key in a `dataframe` like:

```
dict = {"colA":1,"colB":1,"colC":1}
```

with colA, colB, colC the columns of my `dataframe`.

I would like to do something like:

```
df.loc[(df["colA"] < = dict["colA"]) & (df["colB"] < = dict["colB"]) & (df["colC"] < = dict["colC"])]
```

but dynamically (I don't know the length of the dict / number of columns)

Is there a way to do a `&` with dynamic number of arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
from  functools import reduce

df = pd.DataFrame({'colA':[1,2,0],
                   'colB':[0,5,6],
                   'colC':[1,8,9]})

print (df)
   colA  colB  colC
0     1     0     1
1     2     5     8
2     0     6     9

d = {"colA":1,"colB":1,"colC":1}

a = df[(df["colA"] <= d["colA"]) & (df["colB"] <= d["colB"]) & (df["colC"] <= d["colC"])]
print (a)
   colA  colB  colC
0     1     0     1
```

Solution with creating `Series`, compare with [`le`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.le.html), check all `True` by [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) and last use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
d = {"colA":1,"colB":1,"colC":1}

s = pd.Series(d)
print (s)
colA    1
colB    1
colC    1
dtype: int64

print (df.le(s).all(axis=1))
0     True
1    False
2    False
dtype: bool

print (df[df.le(s).all(axis=1)])
   colA  colB  colC
0     1     0     1
```

Another solution with [`numpy.logical_and`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.logical_and.html) and `reduce` for creating mask and `list comprehension` for apply conditions:

```
print ([df[x] <= d[x] for x in df.columns])
[0     True
1    False
2     True
Name: colA, dtype: bool, 0     True
1    False
2    False
Name: colB, dtype: bool, 0     True
1    False
2    False
Name: colC, dtype: bool]

mask = reduce(np.logical_and, [df[x] <= d[x] for x in df.columns])
print (mask)
0     True
1    False
2    False
Name: colA, dtype: bool

print (df[mask])
   colA  colB  colC
0     1     0     1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one SQL-like solution, which uses [.query()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#the-query-method-experimental) method:

Data:

```
In [23]: df
Out[23]:
   colA  colB  colC
0     2     2     5
1     3     0     8
2     5     9     2
3     3     0     2
4     9     1     3
5     7     5     6
6     7     8     0
7     0     4     1
8     8     2     6
9     9     6     7
```

Solution:

```
In [20]: dct = {"colA":4,"colB":4,"colC":4}

In [21]: qry = ' and '.join(('{0[0]} <= {0[1]}'.format(tup) for tup in dct.items()))

In [22]: qry
Out[22]: 'colB <= 4 and colA <= 4 and colC <= 4'

In [24]: df.query(qry)
Out[24]:
   colA  colB  colC
3     3     0     2
7     0     4     1
```